# Real or complex numbers for the general solution of $y''(x)+k^2y(x)=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For $y''(x)+k^2y(x)=0$, we have the general solution 
$$
y(x)=Ae^{-ikx}+Be^{ikx}
$$
But are the constants $A$ and $B$ real or complex numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the initial conditions. In general these constants will be complex. For real initial conditions you get a completely real solution of the ODE, thus $y(x)=\overline{y(x)}$. This implies the additional condition $B=\bar A$ on the complex coefficients. Then the solution is $$y(x)=2\,{\rm Re}(\bar A e^{ikx})=C\cos(kx)+D\sin(kx)$$ where $C=2\,{\rm Re}(A)$ and $D=2\,{\rm Im}(A)$ are real constants.

Comment: Thanks! I think I follow... 
So for real $A$ and $B$ we can write
$$y(x)=Ae^{-ikx}+Be^{ikx} \tag{1}$$ or
$$y(x)=C\cos kx+D\sin kx, \tag{2}$$ 
where $C=A+B$ and $D=(B-A)i$.


But is the form $(2)$ also valid if $A$ and $B$ are complex numbers?

Comment: You mis-understood. For real $y(t_0)$, $y'(t_0)$ the constants $A,B$ will be complex, a complex conjugate pair, and $C=A+B=2\,Re(A)$ and $D=(B-A)i=2\,Im(A)$ are real.